# how to read csv file which should not contains "" or ' or new line and then insert the modified csv into db

Tags: java, regex, apache-poi

i have a csv file which i should read using apache poi,while reading the file it should follow some pattern like data should not have ' or '' or new line like that.After validating we need to insert the validated csv into db.The code which i wrote for this is below.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/insert", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void uploadData(@RequestParam("file") final MultipartFile DataFile,
            @PathVariable("DataType") final String DataType,
            final Model model, final HttpServletRequest request,
            final HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    byte[] bytes = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;

    if (DataFile != null && !DataFile.isEmpty()) {
        inputStream = DataFile.getInputStream();
        LOGGER.info("Making Service call to save imported Enrichment details in DB ");

        if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(DataType, "csvData1")) {
            bytes = enrichmentDataFile.getBytes();
            inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Pattern.compile("(\\r\"|\\n\"|\\r\"\\n\"|\"|\')+")
                        .matcher(new String(bytes)).replaceAll("").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            DataService.insertData(inputStream, 
            DataFile.getOriginalFilename());//reading data using Apache POI and inserting into db
        } else if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(DataType, "csvData2")) {
                DataService.insertData(inputStream, 
                DataFile.getOriginalFilename());//reading data using Apache POI and inserting into db
        }
    }
}
```

iam able to insert csvData2 into db but when iam trying to insert csvData1,it was creating an empty file and that file was inserting into db.
can anyone suggest How can i validate the inputstream(scv) without having any ' or " or new lines and then insert validated one into db

Answer (score 0):

Your InputStream mutation works perfectly. Problem should be in DataService.insertData method.

Comment: if there is problem with my service method then csvData2 should not get inserted but it was working fine the pblm is there with csvData1 that too at that line only

Comment: your service inserted data with quotes and double quotes, but not without it. Try siply send on your service new ByteArrayInputStream("blablabla".getBytes()). I suppose you will get also empty file. Maybe your POI parser requires quotes.

Comment: same again getting empty file in this approach also

Comment: And if you try new ByteArrayInputStream(" 'blablabla' ".getBytes()) or new ByteArrayInputStream(" \"blablabla\" ".getBytes())  content will be probably not empty

Comment: @Wladinir thats what i am doing in my code .matcher(new String(bytes)).replaceAll("").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))

Comment: thats what i am doing in my code .matcher(new String(bytes)).replaceAll("").getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")))

Comment: Yes, I will only show, that problem is in service, not in controller, which makes perfect job